# MaxWidth & MaxHeight options are not available in Instructions in ImageResizer 3.4.2

Tags: imageresizer

Can you please tell me when I use Instructions class in place of ResizeSettings how to use MaxWidth & MaxHeight.

Thanks in advance.

Mohammad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mode=max` with `width` and `height` instead.

`maxwidth` & `maxheight` are still supported in the URL API (and through `Instructions["maxwidth"]`), but to encourage use of the more consistent width/height/mode syntax we omitted the convenience property.